# BS4 findAll html tags with same part of tag name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 for getting html tags of web:

```
html = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(temp_cat_link).text, 'html.parser')
items =html.findAll('h4',{'class':'item-title font-weight-normal '})# this tag have a tag name contain white space at the end
```

but when I check it not actually get all tag because there're some tag name doens't have white space at the end. It's only return `item-title font-weight-normal`  tags. So I changed my code in to this:

```
html = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(temp_cat_link).text, 'html.parser')
items =html.findAll('h4',{'class':'item-title font-weight-normal'})# this tag name doesn't contain white space at the end
```

But it's only get all tags `item-title font-weight-normal`.
The question here is how can I actually get all tag with same string part of name in the html tag

`item-title font-weight-normal` and
`item-title font-weight-normal` 
with just a single line of `html.findAll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regex](http://regexr.com/69jk4) to match the string with or without trailing space:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(temp_cat_link).text, 'html.parser')
items = html.findAll('h4',{'class':re.compile(r'item-title font-weight-normal\s*')})
```